# Is there a way to grant admin access of Bitbucket repo to a future user whose username/email is currently unknown?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I haven't been able to find this yet in Bitbucket settings, I'm wondering if there's a way to grant admin access to a Bitbucket user without knowing their username or email address? For e.g., is there some sort of link I can generate with Bitbucket that would just give anyone with that link admin access to that particular private repo?

I want to do this because I have a repository currently I'm managing alone (I'm the only admin and user), but soon I won't be available and I want someone to be able to take over later without me knowing their Bitbucket username or email. Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe just create a dummy user with admin privileges, and then give the username and password to someone for safekeeping.  Your dummy admin user can always be used in the future to grant additional rights on your repository.

Comment: @larsks That crossed my mind, I'd take that as a last resort solution if there's no other simpler way.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible, I've checked on BitBucket cloud and server, neither, unfortunately, support this feature. You would've to use @larsks suggested approach.

Answer (score 0):

As per larsks' suggestion in the comments, it seems like the only way to do this is to create a dummy email and a dummy Bitbucket account which the future user can use to gain access to the repository. After gaining access, the user may give their original Bitbucket account access to the bitbucket repository and delete the dummy account.